# I misled some users into closing my fence post question. What can be done?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, specific-question

A couple of days ago I posted this question: [How can I make a post base support fenceposts (gateposts) on top of concrete?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274581/how-can-i-make-a-post-base-support-fenceposts-gateposts-on-top-of-concrete?noredirect=1#comment566820_274581)

The form of the question is basically: "How can I do *X*?" with followon information of "I tried *Y*, but *Z* happened."

After quite a few comments, a day later I did made a major edit, including the information that I found another question that was basically "How do I fix *Z*?" That's this question: [Wobbly Gate Post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/203544/wobbly-gate-post)

Now logically, these are not the same question. If there's some other way to accomplish *X*, other than the *Y* -> *Z* path, that's a good answer for me. Not so for the 2 year old question.

Worse, that question only has 2 "answers". I put irony quotes around them, because one just said "don't use *Z*" (probably. They were guessing because the OQ never responded to anything), and the other wasn't actually an answer but rather a request for more information. The OQ neither ever popped back in to supply that extra information, nor to any of the comments. As far as I know they've never logged back into this site again after posting the original question.

Clearly it was a tactical error on my part to even bring up that other (bad) old question. Things were going fairly well before I did that. I'm wondering what I can do to get *actual* answers to my question at this point?

Just out of principle, I'd prefer to see my question reopened, because it is literally **not a duplicate** of that other question. If there's some other reason its bad, fine, but they are not the same question, and **the answers to that other question don't help me**.

Failing that, if you all disagree and really think they are identical, could that question perhaps be the one closed as a dup? The answers could get merged into my question (although again one of them is a bit inapplicable, but that can be dealt with). I know its unusual because that question is years older, and has answers, but..

- The old question was never really resolved. There was no checkmark bestowed, and the answers don't answer my question.
- My question has a slighly larger scope, and is fundamentally more receptive to alternate approaches.
- I've come back and made edits as requested, added further information, and am generally being receptive to feedback. The older question is only a couple of sentences long, and the OP never responded to multiple requests for more information.

Mine is simply a far better version of the question (if indeed you think they are the same).

If you don't like either of those options, I suppose I could try to make "friendly" edits to the existing question. I have a decent idea of what to put down for most of the questions asked there (and if I'm wrong, the OQ doesn't appear to be around to say so). The problem with this is that I don't have the ability to bestow a checkmark for a correct answer, even if most of the text at some point becomes text I wrote.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your question explaining why yours is *not* a duplicate of the other one, showing the differences between the two. By editing it, it will automatically be placed in the "Reopen" review queue, and if enough (3) people agree with you, it will be reopened and you're back in business.

FYI- In general, significant edits to questions that change the direction of what's being asked are generally frowned upon here, especially if it invalidates an existing answer. You've not got any answers yet, so that's not an issue in this case, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Already done. I *thought* it was well explained when I first brought up the website, but I've clarified since closure. Is there something you feel the current edit lacks?

Comment: TBH, the only reference I see is "Note that this aspect (and only this aspect) of my question appears to be related..." and I'm not sure what "this aspect" is that you're referring to. Also, you specifically said "However, I'd like the bit about the post being wobbly addressed", and I think the other question does address that - "No, don't do this".  I do see at least 2 questions in your question, though: 1) post in bracket wobbles, 2) Can I secure fence posts to the top of my retaining wall?

Comment: And, I will 3rd the notion that securing posts to concrete and not expecting them to wobble is _not_ what these kind of post bases will do for you. (But that's addressing the original question, not this meta question.)

Comment: I would kind of like that issue gone into too though. Is the solution to edit it out of my question, and go try to reactivate it in the older question? Note that the older question never responded to requests for clarification about exactly what product was being used. I'm capable of doing that in my case, but of course not in theirs.

Comment: Don't try to resurrect the ancient question w/o any OP feedback! Your title question doesn't really match what you're asking. It seems that the comments on this particular question seem to have focused on the wobbly post & whether or not that base will work for you. Focus the question on that, say _how_ your question is different from the dupe question, and see if you can get some suggestions on yours for fixing the wobbly post. Including a pic of the actual fasteners through the wood might help. Beyond that, I've got nothing for you...